# Network Status shows connection but no network access

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, router

So my problem is that GNOME and NetworkManager all show a functioning wifi connection (GNOME sometimes shows a "?" inside the wifi icon) but I am not able to connect to the network. I assume the question mark shows the missing internet connectivity.
But even though they show a connection and I get an IP address I am not even able to connect to local machines. Neither am I able to ping my router not am I able to ping my own machine from other devices. Additionally my device does not show up inside of the router.

Turning wifi off and on seems to fix the issue for a few moments but only for a minute or two...

Comment: Do you have access control enabled in your router? Have you rebooted your router? Do other machines work properly?

Comment: In a terminal window, does `ip route show` list a `default` route? Type `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` to see Network Manager logs.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I missed the notifications
@heynnema Router has factory settings and rebooting did not fix the problem. Other machines in the same network work properly and same machine in other networks also fails - therefore i think the problem lies at the machine and not the router.

Comment: @waltinator I uploaded the output in this gist: https://gist.github.com/Septatrix/873645b0a32b6e5a7fb9722b1f199150

Comment: What version Ubuntu? See if `sudo iwconfig wlp5s0 power off` helps. Or try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if wireless works then. Also show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Yes the problem did not occur when booting from a live usb. However I also did not again encounter the error when normally booting yet...so maybe my wifi chip was in a weird state somehow which rebooting did not fix but booting to another OS somehow did?